# Trying to access 'content_object' fields in Django under ContentType

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to access the `Item` model through the `Thing` queryset, and keep getting the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.
```

```
class ThingContent(models.Model):

    content_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I have tried updating the fields on `Item` by adding a `related_query_name` to no success.

```
self.queryset.filter(items__item_date=exact_item_date))
```

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    item_date = models.DateField(**options)
    thing_content = GenericRelation('ThingContent', related_query_name='items')
```

Comment: `content_object` is `generic`. You must filter by `object_id` and `content_type` for know what object you FK generic. Because this, line  `content_object__item_date` is wrong.
Can you give more information? What model you want filter in `content_object__item_date` ?

Comment: @NgocPham The fields in thing content include references to objects in Item. I guess I need to be more specific when filtering...but how do I filter to traverse into item from thing content?

Comment: can you post model `Item` ?

Comment: add order_by('exact_item_date') before filter()

Comment: @NgocPham edited post

Comment: I think I'm almost there I just keep getting an empty queryset as a response

Comment: `animals__item_date`, what is `animals` mean? I dont see it in any relation with model?

Comment: @NgocPham Oops, call thst a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content_object` is generic. You must filter by `object_id` and `content_type` for know what object you FK generic.

You try again with query like this:

```
    ThingContent.objects.filter(
        items__item_date=item_date,
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Item)
    )
```

this query mean: find all `ThingContent` have mapping with `Item`, and have `item_date` like what you want filter.